# How to determine a recurrence relation and justification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A message is transmitted by a series of signals from the following 19 signals: s1, s2, ... , S19.

Knowing that the signal s<sub>1</sub> take 1 second, signal s<sub>2</sub> to s<sub>11</sub> take 2 seconds each and the other signals take 3 seconds. a<sub>n</sub> is the number of messages possibles that take n seconds to be transmitted, where n ≥ 1.

a) Calculate a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub> and a<sub>3</sub>
I found that:
a<sub>1</sub> = 1 (1 message of 1 second)
a<sub>2</sub> = 11 (1 message of 2 times 1 second and 10 messages of 2 seconds because there is 10 different 2 seconds signals)
a<sub>3</sub> = 29 (with the same logic)

b) Determine the recurrence relation for n >=4. Justify.
Hint from the teacher: |A<sub>n</sub>| = |B<sub>n</sub>| + |C<sub>n</sub>| + |D<sub>n</sub>|

I have a clue that it will look like a homogenous linear relation:
a<sub>n</sub> = C<sub>1</sub> x a<sub>n-1</sub> + C<sub>2</sub> x a<sub>n-2</sub> + C<sub>3</sub> x a<sub>n-3</sub>

And I think C<sub>1</sub> = 1, C<sub>2</sub> = 10 and C<sub>3</sub> = 8 but I need to prove it with my teacher's clue.

Thus I have : a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + 10a<sub>n-2</sub> + 8a<sub>n-3</sub>

Here's an example with my teacher's method apply to bit string that must have at least two consecutive zeros:
B<sub>n</sub> = {(1, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> : ∀i, a<sub>i</sub> ∈ {0,1}, a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>j+1</sub> = 0}
C<sub>n</sub> = {(0, 1, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> : ∀i, a<sub>i</sub> ∈ {0,1}, a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>j+1</sub> = 0}
D<sub>n</sub> = {(0,0, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> : ∀i, a<sub>i</sub> ∈ {0,1}, a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>j+1</sub> = 0}
A<sub>n</sub> = B<sub>n</sub> ∪ C<sub>n</sub> ∪ D<sub>n</sub>
B<sub>n</sub> ∩ C<sub>n</sub> = ∅
B<sub>n</sub> ∩ D<sub>n</sub> = ∅
C<sub>n</sub> ∩ D<sub>n</sub> = ∅
gives a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub> + $2^{n-2}$
(for 1 at the beginning for n-1, 2 at the beginning for n-2 and 2 times the same for $2^{n-2}$)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n\ge 4$. Any $n$-second message ends in (i) $s_1$; or (ii) one of the $10$ two-second thingies, or (iii) one of the $8$ three-second thingies.

There are $a_{n-1}$ $n$-second messages of Type (i). For every one of the $a_{n-1}$ $(n-1)$-second messages can be extended to a Type (i) $n$-second message in exactly $1$ way, by appending $s_1$.

There are $10a_{n-2}$  Type (ii) $n$-second messages. For every one of the $a_{n-2}$ $(n-2)$-second messages can be extended to a Type (ii) $n$-second message by appending any of the $10$ symbols $s_2$ up to $s_{11}$.

Similarly, there are  $8a_{n-3}$ $n$-second messages of Type (iii). Thus
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+10a_{n-2}+8a_{n-3}.$$

**Added:** If we want to be very set theoretical in our language, we can let $A_n$ be the set of $n$-second messages, $B_n$ the set of $n$-second messages with last signal $s_1$, $C_n$ the set of $n$-second messages with last signal one of $s_2$ to $s_{11}$, and $D_n$ be the set of $n$-second messages with last signal one of $s_{12}$ to $s_{19}$. (**Or else** we classify by *first* signal instead of last, doesn't matter as long as we are consistent.)

Then $a_n=|A_n|$. But $A_n=B_n\cup C_n\cup D_n$, and $B_n$, $C_n$, and $D_n$ are pairwise disjoint. That is, $B_n\cap C_n=\emptyset$, $\dots$.

It follows that 
$$a_n=|A_n|=|B_n|+|C_n|+|D_n|.\tag{1}$$
Now we obtain expressions for $|B_n|$, $|C_n|$, $|D_n|$. We will only deal with 
$|C_n|$.

An elements of $C_n$ has a unique representation as an element of $A_{n-2}$, with one of $s_2,\dots,s_{11}$ appended. Thus by the Multiplication Principle, $|C_n|$ is equal to $|A_{n-2}|$ times the cardinality of the set $\{s_2,\dots,s_{11}\}$. More briefly, $|C_n|=(a_{n-2})(10)=10a_{n-2}$.

Now you can deal similarly with the other two, substitute  in Equation (1) to get the recurrence.`

Comment: yes, that is the relation I wrote, but I need to prove it with my teacher's clue... I wrote that C<sub>1</sub> = 1, C<sub>2</sub> = 10 and C<sub>3</sub> = 8... but it is not a proof just to say that there is 1 time 1 second, 10 times 2 seconds and 8 times 3 seconds.

Comment: The argument I wrote out is a proof that the recurrence relation is correct.

Comment: That is exactly what I said as proof to my teacher, but it was not enough... I need someone who knows about proof with cardinality, sets and subsets, etc. applied to recurrence relation. I answered the rest of the number, but the justification for the b) is not enough.

Comment: If you wrote out something close to what I wrote, I would be surprised if it was not considered a proof. If you just wrote down the recurrence, then of course it would not be considered a proof. One might add to what I wrote something that says **why** there are, for example $10a_{n-2}$ of Type (ii). This is because every $n-2$-second message can be extended to an $n$ second Type (ii) message in $10$ ways.

Comment: Yes, I added (but forgot to add it in my question) that the C's are equals to the number of signals of each types. But he said that An = Bn U Cn U Dn and Bn ∩ Cn = ∅ and  Bn ∩ Dn = ∅ and  Cn ∩ Dn = ∅

So with his example, I think of something like that Bn = {(1, a2, ..., an)... and Cn = {(1, 2, a3, ..., an)... times 10 possible 2's and Dn = {(1, 2, 3, a4, ..., an)... times 8 possible 3's... you don't want to repeat all possible 2's or 3's...

but like I said... I don't really know where to go with this particular method...

Comment: and I clearly understand your explanation, that is the one I have and the one I was going to put as an answer...

Comment: He is using  $A_n$ where I am using Type (1) $n$-second message, and so on for $B_n$, $C_n$. When in the first sentence I say every $n$ second message is of one of these three types, he is saying that the set of $n$-second messages is $A_n\cup B_n\cup C_n$. From the description, I would think it is so obvious that (say) $A_n\cap B_n=\emptyset$ that it is not worth saying. But one can certainly put everything in set-theoretic language.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your help! But that is the tricky part... I don't know how to put it the right way in set-theoretic language... hope someone can help me with that part!

Comment: You already have, sort of. I will add a bit to the post. There may be differences of notation, I expect you can adjust.

Comment: Yes, I can do that! Thank you for your help again

Comment: That could do! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. From my point of view as a mathematician, the answer in the main post is a clearer justification of the recurrence.